# which state to add main menu for simple browser game with phaser

Tags: javascript, browser-based-games, phaser

In which state should I add the main menu, or should i make it into another separate state? 
My main confusion here is how I manipulate states properly. Im a phaser/gamedev noob and I dont know how to start a game from the main menu syntax and mechanics-specific.

My idea for a main menu would be a simple background picture with a start button. But then, how do i jump start the game when the start button is clicked?

just for details, Im showing you this :

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800,600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-demo', {preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately most of the tutorials you'll see will teach you some bad habits as far as state management goes. What you'll want to do here is **avoid the object literal state declaration** in favor of adding states from separate JS files in your index.html.

(Don't forget to include them as `<script>`'s as well.)

```
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS,'YourGameName');
    game.state.add("Boot", Boot);
    game.state.add("Preload", Preload);
    game.state.add("MainMenu", mainMenu);
    game.state.add("Play", Play);
    game.state.add("GameOver", GameOver);
    game.state.start("Boot");
```

I recommend reading the guide to Phaser state management [here](https://leanpub.com/phaserstatemanager/) when it's finished.

Until then we're stuck with kinda skimpy tutorials like [this one](http://gamedolph.in/tutorials/state-management-tiny-tutorial/), that still do the job, but aren't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Jordan replied the question properly, I have given here some resource that might be helpful.

[using state in Phaser](http://perplexingtech.weebly.com/software-blog/using-states-in-phaserjs-javascript-game-developement)

[github template for phaser game](https://github.com/OttoRobba/browserify-phaser/tree/menu)

[in-phaser-how-should-i-be-managing-state](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96115/in-phaser-how-should-i-be-managing-state)

Comment: I've stumbled upon ottoraba's repo before and I am still using it til now :) thats for sharing resources though for me, browserify and beefy are two other things to learn but will pay in the long run! thanks